# Twitter boostrap navigation collapsing not working in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm really struggling getting boostrap navigation to collapse when in Wordpress. I've already built a static site which sits on a server and i've had no problems there. As soon as i've put it into Wordpress it seems you can expand the menu but not collapse it and all javascript looks like it's loaded properly.

Would be amazing if someone could help me out!

Link to the site: http://www.occamsystems.eu/corporate/

Thanks,

Shaun

Answer (score 0):

First I can think of is, you are missing the `.navbar-toggle` button.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
```